# is there a way to perform optional casting in Dart?

Tags: dart

in Swift or Kotlin I can do something like this

```
var fullName = myMap["fullName"] as? String
```

then as a result that `fullName` data type will be optional String ( String? ).

I need to get optional type after type checking like that

I can't directly perform null coalescing operator to that map, because dart will give weird result. for example like this

```
// 'data' is Map<String, dynamic>

final fullName = data["fullname"] ?? "John Doe";
final double myNumber = fullName;
```

[image]

as you can see, the IDE will not show an error at all,  I expect that `fullName` will be a String, so it will have an error when I assign a String to `myNumber` that require double.

Comment: Why can't you just do `var name = myMap["fullName"] ?? "John Doe";`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know in advance that `data["fullname"]` is a `String`, then you could do:

```dart
final fullName = (data["fullname"] ?? "John Doe") as String;
```

If `data["fullname"]` turns out *not* to be a `String` at runtime, you'll get a runtime exception from the cast failure.  If that's something you need to handle, then you could easily make a trivial helper function that checks if a `dynamic` value is the desired type first and that returns `null` if it isn't:

```dart
T? tryCast<T>(dynamic object) => object is T ? object : null;

final fullName = tryCast<String>(data["fullname"]) ?? "John Doe";
```

and now `fullName` is statically known to be a `String`, and accidentally assigning it to a `double` will be a compile-time error.